# SSH Key не работает

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

### Проблема

Пытаюсь настроить подключение к серверу по ssh ключу.

1. Сгенерировал ключ (`ssh-keygen`)
2. Отправил его на сервер (`ssh-copy-id user@server`)
3. Чтобы наверняка проверил `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` на сервере и убедился, что ключ там есть.

**Результат:** при подключении все равно запрашивает пароль.

---

### Дополнение

4. Результат команды "ssh -vvv host":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Попробовал указывать ключ явно (`ssh user@domain -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)
6. Все файлы имеют верные права доступа 600 и 700. Самой папке я также присвоил права доступа 700, было 775.
7. Для профилактики попытался разблокировать пользователя, если вдруг он заблокирован (`sudo passwd -u name`)

**Результат:** для входа требуется пароль.

---

### Решение

Покопавшись в /var/log/auth.log нашел строку Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory. Прогуглил данную ошибку и пришел к величайшему для себя удивлению - ssh важны права не только на папку ~/.ssh и вложенные в нее файлы. Ей также важны права на домашнюю папку, а точнее необходим запрет на запись и изменение файла.

**Мне помогло:**

8. Выдача папке ~/.ssh прав 700 (`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`)
   Выдача файлу с авторизованными ключами прав 600 (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
   Выдача домашней папки прав 755 ('chmod 755 ~/')

Comment: `ssh -vvv <host>` результат коммуникации в студию...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы обоих ключей должны быть **read only**:

```
$ chmod 444 ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
```

а в некоторых случаях недоступны для чтения даже для группы:

```
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
```

Comment: А вообще у меня на всех ssh-файлах стоят права `600` и при этом всё работает (хотя отключение записи всё равно не помешает)

Comment: @Drakonoved, не read only, а недоступны для group и other: `$ chmod -R go= ~/.ssh`. ну и домашний каталог не должен быть доступен для записи other (а лушче и group).